# How initialise and uninitialise serial based on the user's input?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, c-preprocessor

In Summary. If the argument is true, I want to create a function that prints the necessary stuff into the serial. However, if its false serial is uninitialised and does not print anything, it only executes the code.
The code below does not work, but it's an example code to show what I mean.

```
bool status;
void setDebug(bool x){
 if (x){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  status = true;
 }
else {
 status = false;}
}
void setup(){
 setDebug(true);
}
void loop(){
Serial.println("Hello World");
}
```

I have found a few solutions that might be beneficial

1. If Statement - This overall code works; however, I am looking for a better and more efficient way to do this

```
void loop(){
 if (status){
  Serial.println("Hello World");
 }
}
```

2. Preprocessor directive - I have seen many libraries use #ifdef DEBUG, which works. However, I want to be able to  change it through a function, and the preprocessor directives won't allow me to do that

```
void loop(){
 #ifdef DEBUG
  Serial.println("Hello World");
 #endif
}
```

How else can I achieve this?